# Convert a list from type str to type list

Tags: python

It must be simple, but I don't know it:

I've got a *file.json* with this content

```
[{u'key': u'value1'},{u'key': u'value2'}]
```

and imported it as `data`

```
with open(file.json) as fd:
        data = fd.read()
```

I'm quite happy that this works

```
>>> print (data)
[{u'key': u'value1'},{u'key': u'value2'}]
```

But unfortunately `data` is now converted as `str`

```
>>> print(type(data))
<type 'str'>
```

So I can't use `data` to do things like deleting items.

How do I convert `data` to a normal list of dicts? (`<type 'list'>`)

Comment: Given that you know the file is JSON data, why not use [the `json` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)?

Comment: That's not JSON. Where did you get that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the file method `.read()`, you always get a string. You'd have to parse it yourself, but fortunately, Python has a [`json` module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) that does all the parsing for you. It even reads the file:

```
import json
with open(file.json) as fd:
    data = json.load(fd)
```

But, as Stefan has pointed out, your file isn't valid JSON - it rather looks like the `repr()` output of a Python object. In that case, it's nearly as simple:

```
import ast
with open(file.json) as fd:
    data = ast.literal_eval(fd.read())
```

Comment: Have you tried it with their data? It doesn't work for me, as their data isn't valid JSON.

Comment: @StefanPochmann: Indeed, it's not valid JSON. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: @Stefan You're probably right. OP opened file as a string, and printed it (as a string, not JSON), so you're saying the unicode markers are in the file

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes, and also the single quotes which should be double quotes.

Comment: @Stefan I got this strange file by myself. I converted a csv to a list named `result` and saved it with `file.write(str(result))`. With your hints I solved my problem by not creating it. I just saved my list with `json.dump(result,file)` and now I can import it like @Tim describes (`json.load(file)`). Thanks a lot to all!

Answer (score 1):

Very simple with json library.

```
import json
obj = json.loads(json_string)
```

Deserialize json_string (json_string is str or unicode instance containing a JSON document) to a Python object (dixt in our case).

**EDIT:**

As Stefan mention, this is not a valid json(it looks like a list) and therefore you can see Tim's answer.

Comment: You can load the file directly, no need for the string

Comment: You right, but Tim already wrote this answer so i don't want to duplicate his answer. @cricket_007

Comment: Have you tried it with their string? It doesn't work for me, as their data isn't valid JSON.

Comment: @StefanPochmann , You right, i've added a code that support the string the OP has. Thanks !

Comment: @omri_saadon That new code doesn't work for me, just puts the string as a whole into a weird array (doesn't even allow accessing with `...[0]`). Also, you changed their data, removed the `u` prefixes.

Comment: @StefanPochmann well, that's because it's type is ndarray, i didn't want to copy Tim's answer so tried to be creative.